# Designer drag and drop option is not displaying to make mobile app using xamarin in visual studio 2017

Tags: visual-studio, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm using xamarin to make a mobile app in Visual Studio 2017. I have to make UI for mobile app. I'm able to make UI using code but I want to use drag & drop option. I think we can use drag & drop to make UI instead of coding.

But I'm not able to find designer view. 
Any idea what I'm missing for it?

[image]

Comment: There is no drag/drop UI designer for Xamarin's XAML

Comment: @SushiHangover have you seen this one?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/creating-a-ui-by-using-xaml-designer-in-visual-studio

Comment: That does not handle **Xamarin**'s XAML

Comment: We can use blend visual studio tool? to use Xamarin's XAML drag/drop option.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/creating-a-ui-by-using-blend-for-visual-studio

Comment: Blend does not support the Xamarin namespace. You could use it and later convert its XAML *manually* to Xamarin's XAML, but with Xamarin's limited support of the full WPF/UWP XAML your results will be different than what Blend shows you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no drag & drop designer for Xamarin.Forms.

You will have to compose the XAML by hand. You can, howeverm use tools like LiveXAML or the Xamarin Live Player and Xamarin Live Reload to see changes in your XAML without recompilation.

LiveXAML is third-party and paid but works rather well. Information can be found on: http://livexaml.com

More information on Live Player: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/tools/live-player/

More information on Live Reload: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/xaml/live-reload

Comment: We can use blend visual studio tool? to use Xamarin's XAML drag/drop option.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/designers/creating-a-ui-by-using-blend-for-visual-studio

Comment: No, this uses a different dialect of XAML. It will mostly be compatible, but you will probably spend more time figuring out what the differences are than creating the XAML yourself.

Answer (score 2):

There is no designer for Xamarin.Forms. You have to write code, but there are several tools for live previewing XAML, Xamarin Live Reload, Xamarin Live Player, LiveXAML and Gorilla Player for example.